# Bootstrap Error massages not working in IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to display a error massage when user trying to upload incorrect format of the sheet.For this I am using bellow code segment,

**In Controller :-**

```
TempData["Error"] = "Cannot contain null values in the Excel sheet";
```

**In View :-**

```
 @if (TempData["Error"] != null)
    {
        <div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Error!  </strong>@TempData["Error"].ToString()
            </div>
        </div>

    }
```

This works as expected when I run this in localhost but when I try this in IIS sever this does't work(It is not showing correct bootstrap error massage ,it shows "An error occurred while processing your request") this is not a error massage instead of getting proper bootstrap error massage,I am getting above massage

And also I am using bootstrap success massage that works well in both localhost and IIS server bellow is code segment for that

```
 @if (TempData["Success"] != null)
    {
        <div>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>Success!  </strong>@TempData["Success"].ToString()
            </div>
        </div>

    }
```

I can't understand the solution for this problem

Comment: if you put in an else in your view, and say "No error detected" or something, are you getting that message? what debugging have you done?

Comment: It says ``An error occurred while processing your request.``

Comment: Is the any redirection going on here, e.g. `RedirectToAction`? Because TempData only survives  for the current request. BTW Bootstrap has a [built in alert system](https://web.archive.org/web/20140626022423/http://jameschambers.com/2014/06/day-14-bootstrap-alerts-and-mvc-framework-tempdata/)

Comment: No there is no any redirection ,this works well in localhost cant be a problem in IIS server?

Comment: there are likely more hints on the iis server logs as to what the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to say that I found the reason for my own question, I used global exception handling in my code as I mentioned bellow ,

```
             }catch(Exception ex)
             {
                LogLastError(ex);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                TempData["Error"] = "Cannot contain null values in the Excel sheet";


         }

        public void LogLastError(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext con = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Page          : " + con.Request.Url.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("Error Message : " + ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("Inner Message : " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
            }

            string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Errors"), 
            DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".txt");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());
        }
```

Therefore, whenever the exception is handled exception massage will be displayed from my Error.cshtml